# installing Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.4 in Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, weblogic12c

I want to install Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.4 in Ubuntu but I have this error:

```
nunyet@lw202050777:~/Downloads$ java -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls_lite_generic.jar 
Launcher log file is /tmp/OraInstall2020-10-13_04-12-07PM/launcher2020-10-13_04-12-07PM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . Done
The OpenJDK JVM is not supported on this platform.
The log is located here: /tmp/OraInstall2020-10-13_04-12-07PM/launcher2020-10-13_04-12-07PM.log.
```

Comment: Docker is your friend (if this is an option?) https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-weblogic-server-12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are trying to install Fusion Middleware or similar and you only need some of the files you can actually force the installer to accept OpenJDK:

- Open the OUI Installer JAR with a ZIP utility and extract the `oraparam.ini` file (located e.g. under `Disk1/install`)
- In the extracted file look for the `VM_TYPES` line and add the name of the Java VM as it was shown in the error message (`The {0} JVM is not supported`…) separated by comma
- Save the file
- Launch the installer as `java -jar <installer.jar> -paramFile <edited file.ini>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with your JVM, download and install a later version of the Java SDK and try again, failing that please upload the log.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic Server does not work and is not supported with OpenJDK, you "must" use Oracle JDK to run it.